# gulp sourcemaps and chrome developer not working together when two plugins are used

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here is the task:

```
gulp.src(widget + "/Widget.es6")
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(babel({ modules: 'amd' }))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename('Widget.js'))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./' + widget + "/"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(widget + "/"));
```

The issue is that when i place a break in GC Developer  in the resulting minified Widget.js it takes me back to some other Widget.js that is not minified (but not the original Widget.es6). I assume this is the product of the babel pipe. In other words GCD is interpreting the sourcemap and taking me back one step in the chain (just beyond the uglification).

If I comment out the uglification, then the sourcemap works (i.e. I get taken back from Widget.js (now not minified) -> Widget.es6 (ES6 file).

I was hoping that the source map would take me back from minified Widget.js -> ES6 file (which is just after the `sourcemaps.init()` call).